# Http response.ContentLength always return -1 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest

I am trying to measure the content length in ASP.Net application as showen:

```
Stopwatch sto = new Stopwatch();
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com");

                sto.Start();
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
                sto.Stop();

                int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode; //save status code as int
                if (response!= null) //reply.Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
                {

                    pinglbl.Text += "Latncy: " + sto.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " s";
                    pinglbl.Text += "\r Status Code: " + statusCode;
                    pinglbl.Text += "\r Content Lenghth: " + response.ContentLength +"MB";

                }
                else
                    pinglbl.Text = "fail ping";
```

i always getting this output:
 Here is the resultLatncy: 0.6525514 s Status Code: 200 Content Length: **-1MB**

is there any issue of keep getting -1 as the content Length ?

Comment: I'm guessing the response doesn't actually include a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: @CoryNelson yeas -1 means that but i have tried many other urls but still same output.

Answer (score 3):

As described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The ContentLength property contains the value of the Content-Length header returned with the response. If the Content-Length header is not set in the response, **ContentLength is set to the value -1.**

Comment: i have read this as you mentioned, but all the tutorials i have saw they wrote the same code - like what i have - but they get different result other than -1

Comment: thake this as an example 

[link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just open your URL say in chrome with dev tools opened, and look for Content-Length header in response - you won't see it. Try another site which does provide this header.

Comment: Ok will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that all links tested as input wasn't containing any content length, I have tried [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/outlookcaldavsynchronizer/files/2.17.0/OutlookCalDavSynchronizer-2.17.0.zip/download?use_mirror=superb-dca2&r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2F&use_mirror=superb-dca2) link from SourceForge and it works fine.